# Правильно ли говорить "сильно лучше"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Корректна ли фраза "сильно лучше"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Сильно лучше*** ― ненормированное сочетание, поэтому говорить так неправильно. Можно сказать: **гораздо лучше, намного лучше, значительно лучше**.

Но ведь в речи **можно встретить** такое сочетание, на форумах например:

С середины 90-х стала писать, хотя вряд ли это кормит **сильно лучше,** чем биология. [Юлия Рахаева. Полный абсурд. Книжный развал (2002) // «Известия», 2002.08.27]

Ну... повоевали поляков ― посадили себе на шею Романовых, **сильно лучше** что ли стало? [Национал-анархизм (форум) (2006)

Даже писатели позволяют себе  иногда "неправильные сочетания": Она ― не то что бы **не сильно лучше** ― но, все-таки, лучше. [Александр Клейн. Виктор Шендерович // «Пятое измерение», 2002]

**Почему? Это сленговая грамматика**. Пользователи могут понимать  неправильность сочетания и используют его для выразительности речи там, где считают это уместным. Гораздо хуже, если они этого не понимают и считают такую речь правильной.

**О сочетаемости**

**Сочетаемость слов** ― фундаментальное понятие русского языка, которое изучается в специальной лингвистике. Также существуют словари сочетаемости, например:

```
Вопрос № 270380
```

Добрый день! Очень интересует следующий вопрос. **Есть ли какие-то пособия, позволяющие оценить сочетаемость слов?** В силу специфики работы часто приходится сталкиваться с необходимостью корректировать тексты. Порой неясно, может ли то или иное слово сочетаться с другим. Я имею в виду такие словосочетания, как "оказывать действие", "производить эффект" и многие другие. Очень давно волнует этот вопрос, поэтому очень жду ответа.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

Да, такие справочники есть. Один из самых полных: Словарь сочетаемости слов русского языка / Под ред. П. Н. Денисова, В. В. Морковкина. – 3-е изд., испр. – М., 2002. Среди онлайн-справочников – Словарь глагольной сочетаемости непредметных имен русского языка (это один из экспериментальных словарей, созданных на основе Национального корпуса русского языка с участием сотрудников Отдела корпусной лингвистики и лингвистической поэтики Института русского языка им. В. В. Виноградова РАН).

А можно ли **без словаря** сравнить сочетаемость слов ***значительно лучше и сильно лучше?*** (Первый вариант нормированный, а второй нет).

**Во-первых,** нет необходимости в расширении существующего ряда синонимов: значительно, намного, гораздо.

**Во-вторых,** можно посмотреть словарные статьи для этих наречий и прилагательных, от которых они образованы.

Прилагательное ***сильный*** связано прежде всего с физической силой, энергией, хотя и может развивать количественное  значение: 4. Значительный (по величине, степени проявления). С-ое чувство. С-ая лихорадка. С-ое лекарство. С. запах ацетона.

Для прилагательного ***значительный*** центральным является именно оценочное значение: "большой по величине".

**Вывод.** Из этих рассуждений становится понятным, что шансы у наречия "сильно" на нормированную сочетаемость невелики, но в качестве сленга иногда использовать его можно, но не всегда и не в любой компании.

Answer (score 2):

"Сильно лучше" звучит не очень. Другое дело "не сильно лучше". Вот это выражение в разговорной речи используется часто, а раз так – протестовать бессмысленно.

Comment: А я протестую. Бессмысленно, но принципиально. :)  "Ненормированное" (@Ксения) сочетание в той же мере, что и *сильно лучше*.

Answer (score 1):

Абсолютно некорректна (если это не стилизация под диалект).

Рассказывает Справка Грамоты.ру о наречии "сильно" + сравнительная степень прилагательного:

**[Вопрос № 292228](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5)**

> Здравствуйте! Допустимо ли выражение "сильно больше" в разговорном
>   контексте и в литературной речи? Спасибо.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Это сочетание не следует использовать в речи.

Comment: **Это сочетание не следует использовать в речи** - это весь ответ? Простите, но как Вы считаете, если бы такой ответ кто-то опубликовал здесь от своего имени, именно в такой форме, одной фразой, без ссылки на какие-либо нормы русского языка, то что бы сказали этому "эксперту"? В лучшем случае - попросили бы отредактировать ответ и добавить аргументацию.

Comment: Грамота не даёт развернутых ответов почти никогда. И это, в общем, правильно.

Comment: @Niemand, мне кажется, что в данном вопросе, где не последнюю роль играет субъективный фактор, аргументация как минимум желательна, а скорее - обязательна. Если такую аргументацию не сочли нужным предоставить на "Грамоте", то ее должен разъяснить участник, цитирующий этот ресурс. Иначе возникает более чем странная ситуация: мнение анонимного автора с "Грамоты" имеет больший вес, чем подробная аргументация, которую, например, изложил в своем ответе я. Неужели в "Грамоте" работают боги, не способные ошибаться, и все их ответы нужно принимать на веру, не требуя подтверждений?

Comment: А какая у вас аргументация? *Соответственно, вполне уместны уточнения степени этого отличия: "чуть лучше", "немного лучше", "сильно лучше" и т.д.* – это вся аргументация? "Сильно лучше" явно выбивается из вашего ряда, зато вполне подходит "много лучше" – и это действительно корректно. По-вашему, и "сильно хорошо" формально корректно?

Comment: Есть устойчивое сочетание "гораздо лучше" (более формальные варианты: намного, значительно, существенно), по сравнению с которым выражение из вопроса звучит косноязычно, оставляет впечатление, что говорящий не в состоянии подобрать подходящеее слово или намеренно проявляет языковую агрессию. Даже эмоциональное "куда лучше" убивает рассматриваемый "изыск".

Comment: @Niemand, у меня в ответе чуть больше текста, чем Вы процитировали, но главное не это. Главное то, что у меня В ПРИНЦИПЕ какая-то аргументация ЕСТЬ. Возможно, не идеальная, возможно - и вовсе ошибочная. Но она ЕСТЬ, ее можно обсуждать, в ней можно находить недостатки, о ее весомости можно спорить и в этом споре может родиться истина. А если просто сказать: "должно быть так и ВСЁ", то это будет больше походить на цитирование средневекового догмата, чем на современную цивилизованную дискуссию. Разве нет?

Comment: Спрашивальщикам Грамоты чаще всего нужен простой ответ: правильно или нет, нужна запятая или нет и т.д. Но главное не это. Аргументы просто ради аргументов (чтобы ответ был подлиннее) – зачем?

Comment: @Niemand, аргументы нужны не ради аргументов, а ради предоставления всем участникам обсуждения возможности дать этим аргументам какую-либо оценку. Безапелляционные утверждения в духе "так и ВСЁ" вряд ли уместны в дискуссии образованных людей. Именно об этом я и хотел сказать. Я понимаю, что нахваливать свой собственный ответ не  слишком корректно, поэтому давайте посмотрим на ответы других участников. Каждый из этих ответов в большей или меньшей степени аргументирован. С приведенными аргументами можно соглашаться или не соглашаться, но они ЕСТЬ. В отличие от комментируемого сейчас нами ответа.

Answer (score 1):

*Сильно* говорит о силе проявления (сильно обидел — нанес обиду большой силы). Оно не стоит в ряду неопределённо-количественных числительных, к которым относится слово *немного* из вопроса. *Лучше* выражает сравнение, с ним уместны неопределённо-количественные числительные, но неверно говорить "лучше с большой силой". А как сленг — пожалуйста, у сленга свои правила.

Comment: Наречие "сильно" образовано от прилагательного "сильный", а оно может быть синонимом прилагательного "значительный". Получается, что наречия "сильно" и "значительно" тоже могут быть синонимами. Кроме того, "сильно" имеет также значение "очень". Таким образом,лексические значения слов пересекаются, поэтому и кажется, что сочетаемость у них должна быть похожей, но это не так.

Comment: Ксения, суть аргумента здесь в  том, что исходное слово "сила" как величина имеет физическую _размерность_ (это количество конкретных физических единиц), которая переносится на производные слова, напр. сильный = обладающий силой, а не отвлечённо "большой" (слово, синонимичное "значительному"). Не всякое слово подходит для чисто количественных корректировок сравнительной степени прилагательного.

Comment: У прилагательного "сильный" есть значение "значительный в своем проявлении".  Получается что-то вроде значительного  проявления сравнительной степени. Кстати, нашла в Нацкорпусе выражения "сильно дешевле" и "сильно дороже", да еще у приличных авторов. http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F1%E8%EB%FC%ED%EE+%E4%E5%F8%E5%E2%EB%E5